# warning truthy value should be true or false (truthy) in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am testing ansible playbook using travis and molecule.
but i am getting below error.

```
   /home/travis/build/hemanth22/hemanth22.centosgui/handlers/main.yml
      8:12      warning  truthy value should be true or false  (truthy)
```

Code link: https://github.com/hemanth22/ansible-role-centosgui/blob/master/handlers/main.yml

Test result: https://travis-ci.org/hemanth22/ansible-role-centosgui/jobs/458286102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also replace `yes` with `true` and `no` with `false`

Answer (score 3):

As i read the error message, it's `Yamllint` which produces the error. Make all lowercase:

```
force: true
```